# Как перевести «trap representation»?

Tags: переводы

В стандарте языка программирования С определен такой термин, как «trap representation»:

> #### 3.19.4
>
> **trap representation**
>
> an object<sup>1</sup> representation<sup>2</sup> that need not represent a value<sup>3</sup> of the object<sup>4</sup> type

Суть trap representation вкратце такова.

Допустим, у нас в памяти компьютера есть область размером в 1 байт, в которой хранятся биты `1000 1010`. Назовем ее A.

Допустим также, что у нас есть два типа размером 1 байт: `целое-число` и `дробное-число`. Тип `целое-число` не имеет trap representation, то есть любая комбинация из 8 бит является корректным значением типа `целое-число`. В то же время тип `дробное-число` имеет одно trap representation — `1000 0000`.

Тогда если мы попытаем использовать то, что находится в A как значение типа `целое-число`, то все будет нормально, так как `1000 1010` не является trap representation для типа `целое-число`. Использовать — применить в арифметическом выражении (A + 3) или, допустим, в сравнении (A > 9) и т. д.

Тогда если мы попытаем **использовать** то, что находится в A **как значение типа `дробное-число`**, то получим ошибку, потому что комбинация битов `1000 0000` является trap representation для типа `дробное-число`.

Как можно настолько же выразительно перевести этот термин на русский язык?

*P. S. Прошу прощение за такое большое количество сносок и объяснений. Просто попытался как можно точнее обозначить контекст использования этого термина.*

---

<sub>1) **object** — region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values.</sub>
<sub>2) **representation** — грубо говоря, просто определенный набор битов в памяти.</sub>
<sub>3) **value** — precise meaning of the contents of an object when interpreted as having a specific type.</sub>
<sub>4) **object** — region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values.</sub>

Comment: Вы не там задали свой вопрос, как мне кажется. Для перевода терминов нужно хорошо знать предметную область и понимать смысл термина. Знание собственно языка тут вторично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильным переводом, или по крайней мере, переводом, передающим смысл, будет *"представление, вызывающее исключение"*.

Относительно других ответов замечу, что в программирование слово *trap* со времён как минимум PDP-11 обозначает именно исключение либо прерывание, но ни в коем случае не *ловушку*. Нет в программировании никаких ловушек, вообще нет! Не стоит переводит дословно непонятные термины, они от этого становятся ещё более непонятными.

Comment: Не такой красивый вариант, как «неполное представление», но более точный как мне кажется. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 3):

Буквальный перевод (*представление с подвохом*) вряд ли подойдёт для термина. Из английского определения следует, что это "***неполное*** представление (репрезентация)" объекта (*числа* в вашей интерпретации): это представление может не содержать *информацию о типе* объекта (эта информация в виде числового значения, соотв. "типу", отделена от такой репрезентации), вследствие чего при попытке интерпретировать такое представление, не располагая информацией о типе, можно (буквально) попасть в "*ловушку*" (trap), - в вашем примере можно *по ошибке* работать с целым числом как с дробным, что обнаружится только при появлении запрещённого дробного значения.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный вариант, но я не уверен, удачен ли он. *«…это представление может не содержать информацию о типе объекта…»*. Представление и не должно содержать информацию о типе: набор битов в памяти — это просто бессмысленный набор битов. Смысл этому набору придает наша интерпретация: `01000001` — это число 64, но в то же время и символ `A`. Причем сначала мы можем интерпретировать этот участок памяти как число, а затем как символ. Поэтому, я не уверен, можно ли применить термин «неполное представление», как вы считаете?

Comment: Представление _неполное_ в том смысле, что не содержит информации о том, **как** его можно интерпретировать. Если вы знаете, что это за объект (пусть из ограниченного набора возможных), то сможете работать с этими данными, если нет, то вам сначала придётся каким-то образом выяснить, вольты это или литры; в простейшем случае (отличить целое от дроби) прогнать какие-нибудь тесты на запрещённые значения. В этом смысле _полное_ представление могло бы иметь напр. заголовок для идентификации типа объекта.

Comment: В таком смысле все представления неполные, потому что ни одно из них не содержит информацию о том, как его можно интерпретировать. Зная, что у нас в памяти есть байт `01000001` мы никак не можем выяснить «вольты это или литры». Мы можем лишь, как вы правильно заметили, исключить *некоторые* типы, проверив эту комбинацию битов на trap representation для этих некоторых типов.

Comment: Если есть заголовок (отведенные биты) и известно, из какого набора вариантов выбирать (таблица значений заголовка), то это условно _полная_ информация. Есть и другие возможности (включая скрытые, скремблинг и прочее) заложить эти данные в код, а перед началом (или в процессе) работы с переменной извлечь данные о типе проведением дополнительной процедуры.

Comment: Но у нас нет такого заголовка. Все, что у нас есть — это сырые биты и байты. Мы можем интерпретировать их как захотим. `11111001 10011010 10011001 00101100` может быть знаковым числом, может быть беззнаковым числом, может быть массивом, может быть структурой — да вообще чем угодно. На самом деле, мне уже довольно сложно что-то утверждать, поскольку я не настолько хорошо знаю стандарт языка.

Comment: @eanmos Гм, неужели никто не удосужился перевести С99 на русский до сих пор? Хотя - зачем... По описанию лучше всего подходит "недопустимое значение" просто напросто. И, насколько я могу понять, там не происходит никакой ошибки - просто UB (undefined behaviour).

Comment: @eanmos Вот тут народ так и пишет ["Представление ловушки"](http://qaru.site/questions/5052/trap-representation) или "ловушечное представление". Похоже нет нормального русского термина.

Comment: "Ловушечное" - _самый_ неумелый перевод, поскольку создаёт бессмысленное для русского языка словосочетание и лишь выдает переводческий дилетантизм переводивших. Я поначалу рассматривал "_ложную репрезентацию_ (представление)" - такой термин есть в других дисциплинах - но по смыслу он противоречит определению ("представление, для которого не требуется присутствие значений, определяющих тип объекта"), ложные же результаты здесь (ошибка, ловушка) - одно из возможных следствий необязательности информации о типе (напр. целая/дробная величина), т. е. _неполноты_ информации.

Comment: @tum_, наличие хотя бы одного UB в коде делает программу бессмысленной (compiled program is not required to do anything meaningful). Так что, грубо говоря, это ошибка. Ссылка, которую вы привели — это сайт с автоматическими переводами вопросов и ответов enSO :)

Comment: @Alex_ander, но опять же, у объекта (а следовательно и его представления) нет такого свойства как *тип*. Тип — это свойство lvalue, которое используется для доступа к этому объекту. В стандарте фраза «тип объекта» понимается как «тип lvalue, указывающего на этот объект», а «значение объекта» как «содержимое объекта, интерпретируемого как некоторое значение типа lvalue, указывающего на этот объект». Это из «Rationale for International Standard».

Comment: Вообще говоря, "неполное представление" - это совсем другое. Как пример, можно вспомнить значения Inf и NaN числа с плавающей точкой. Неполное представление никак не связано с исключением. Даже недопустимое значение далеко не всегда вызывает исключение - та же плавающая точка хороший пример. Именно "исключение" - я, пожалуй, не буду комментировать эту дичь про "ловушку", потому что это просто рукалицо.

Comment: "Плаваящая точка" - тянущееся следствие плохого перевода: русский математический термин - "плавающая **запятая**". Растолкуйте, пожалуйста, что именно в программировании называют "исключением" -  я с этим не сталкивался.

Comment: Исключение (exception), как и прерывание (interrupt) - это прерывание потока выполнения по наступлению какого-либо события. Событием может быть внешний сигнал (от устройства в/в, например), исключительная ситуация (например, переполнение), или программная команда. Про исключение мы говорим обычно в контексте языка высокого уровня, тогда как прерывание относится к уровню процессора. Там есть много нюансов, но в первом приближении это вещи схожие. Слово trap не является строго определённым термином,  этим словом обычно обозначают исключительную ситуацию без спецификации конкретного механизма.

Comment: Программирование все-таки не математика, плавающей запятой там нет. В языках программирования это именно плавающая точка, поскольку синтаксис ЯВУ строго специфицирован и не зависит от локали среды.

Answer (score 2):

Я чуть-чуть занимаюсь переводом документации, поэтому решился добавить пять копеек.

Мне кажется, что если Вы занимаетесь переводом, то нужно переводить. Если написано trap representation, то нужно переводить как представление-ловушка. Всё остальное будет искажением смысла текста (стандарта).

Когда кто-то будет выполнять обратный поиск, он должен получить значения "ловушка" и "представление" для этих слов. Вводя новые знаки Вы усложните отображение смысла.

Буду рад узнать окончательную версию перевода!

Comment: Если речь идёт о термине, то его обычно не "переводят", а ставят ему в соответствие общепринятый русский термин. Например, если упоминается _escape velocity_, то это не "скорость убегания", а "вторая космическая скорость". В нашем случае устоявшегося русского термина, по-видимому, нет, поэтому окончательный перевод невозможен. Буквальный же перевод может создать плохой прецедент для закрепления словосочетания, вводящего в заблуждение относительно содержания термина. В таких случаях буквальный перевод лучше оставлять в _комментарии_, оставив окончательное решение техническим специалистам.